# Redirect rule in .htaccess is taking me to the wrong place

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm having trouble with redirecting urls using the .htaccess file. This is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
Redirect 301 /file-name/example.php http://www.mysite.com/file-name/example-001.php
Redirect 301 /section-name/example.php http://www.my-site.com/section-name/example-002.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.*)$ hqtemplates/articles.php?file_name=$2 [L]
php_value session.use_only_cookies 1
php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
```

Now the problem is that when I go to page: `www.my-site.com/file-name/example.php`, instead of redirecting me to `www.my-site.com/file-name/example-001.php` it redirects me to
`www.my-site.com/file-name/example.php?file_name=example-001.php`.

**For some reason it adds "?file_name=example-001.php" to the url**. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is mixing `mod_alias` redirect rules with `mod_rewrite`. the solution is to stick to one. this is a solution for a pure mod_rewrite only approach (i have included only relevant portions to the issue):

```
RewriteEngine on
# emulate specific mod_alias Redirect rules
#
# Flags explanation:
#   [L] = last rule, stop processing further rules
#   [R=301] = 301 Redirect
#
RewriteRule ^file-name/example.php$ http://www.mysite.com/file-name/example-001.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^section-name/example.php$ http://www.my-site.com/section-name/example-002.php [L,R=301]

# handle other rewrite requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.*)$ hqtemplates/articles.php?file_name=$2 [L]
```

as to what's happening in your .htaccess, here's the rewrite log:

```
(2) rewrite 'file-name/example.php' -> \
        'hqtemplates/articles.php?file_name=example.php'
(2) strip document_root prefix: /home/test/hqtemplates/articles.php -> \
         /hqtemplates/articles.php
(1) internal redirect with /hqtemplates/articles.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
(1) pass through /home/test/Sites/file-name/example-001.php
```

which suggests:

1. apply `mod_rewrite` "RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.*)$ hqtemplates..."
2. `file-name/example.php` is now equivalent to `hqtemplates/articles.php?file_name=example.php`
3. apply `mod_alias` "Redirect 301..."
4. show final `file-name/example-001.php?file_name=example.php`